# Grails search function/solution needed

Tags: grails

I have a web page in my Grails application that has five or six check boxes and two input fields. I have to perform a tailored search function on some database records depending on which check boxes are checked and what is typed in the input fields. I don't know of an efficient way of how to tell my search function how to determine how to look up the records other than using lots of if/else's to determine which check boxes were checked and what was in the input fields. Is there another technique to build a search criteria using a map or something like that? I'm just brainstorming here.

Comment: Maybe if you put your first attempt.

Comment: Does Google force you to check boxes to search for shopping sites vs tech sites? No, then don't force your users to do this. Use a proper search engine like SOLR/ElasticSearch/HibernateSearch and just let the natural relevancy ranking return the best hits (you can use facets to refine a search _after_ the user has hit 'search', if you must).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) obviously or it's descendants. There's also [Searchable Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) which is good for rapid prototyping and some really simple tasks.

Comment: I cannot do a Google like search as the user above suggested. I have my check boxes and text fields' information submitted as a form and then depending on which check boxes are checked, I want to build a search criteria(e.g. US Citizen, registered voter, over 18, male). Of course the criteria would change depending on check boxes but the data set being searched on is the same. Then, my search function could somehow use the criteria (a map?) to tailor its algorithm. If I am making any sense, is this possible? feasible? Thanks.

Comment: Lucene is not about full-text search only. It works well with any combination of criteria. To give you an idea on how `Lucene` can be used, see http://www.boker.de/messerfinder.html